# Lazy evaluation of computed project.version

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use the [Jgitver Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/jgitver/gradle-jgitver-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/brouillard/oss/gradle/plugins/JGitverPlugin.java#L24) together with the [BuildConfig Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin/releases) but I'm not getting the version in the generated BuildConfig class. Instead I get `Unspecified`.

This is because of ordering and so far I wasn't able to get the ordering right. Jgitver doesn't use a task and sets the project version in the `afterEvaluate` phase, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jgitver/gradle-jgitver-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/brouillard/oss/gradle/plugins/JGitverPlugin.java#L24).

The way to go seems to be lazy evaluation [as described here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-control-configuration-order-of-two-plugins/19225/15). I couldn't figure out how to do this with the Kotlin DSL though.

#### Code example

```
plugins {

    java
    id("de.fuerstenau.buildconfig") version "1.1.8"
    id("fr.brouillard.oss.gradle.jgitver") version "0.9.1"
}

configure<BuildConfigExtension> {

    afterEvaluate { /* type mismatch for provider { project.version } if I remove this block

        version = provider { project.version }

        clsName = "BuildConfig" /* The name of the class that contains the build config */
        packageName = "com.somegroup"
        charset = "UTF-8"
    }
}
```

I also tried another approach `val lazyVersion: Provider<String> = providers.provider { () -> project.version }` and then use `lazyVersion` but that doesn't compile: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Any! but String was expected`.

Another thing I tried is to add afterEvaluate to the configure closure as [described in this Jgitver issue](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver/issues/77#issuecomment-470229130), but it doesn't work for me. Probably because the order in which afterEvaluate closures are executed is undefined.

#### Question

What's the recommended way to get the value of `project.version` *after* it was set by Jgitver in afterEvaluate? And what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Regarding your second approach, you must use `toString()` for `project.version`, because it is defined as `Object`.

Comment: Indeed! That makes sense then, but it still doesn't compile: `Type mismatch: inferred type is (Any?) -> String! but (() -> TypeVariable(T)!)! was expected`. I'm not that familiar with Kotlin, but in Java such a lamba would compile now that it returns String if I'm not mistaken. What am I missing?